# CXF generates java code with wrong parameters

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, cxf

I have the problem that when I generate code from wsdl and xsds with cxf, the PortType ends up having the content of both input-type and output-type as parameters. This does not happen in the old Axis2-implementation. Cxf also makes it a void-method instead of returning the response-type. Using  cxf 2.5.3

From the WSDL:

```
<portType name="PortType">
    <operation name="getResponse">
        <input message="ns:Request"/>
        <output message="ns:Response"/>
        <fault name="Error" message="ns:Error"/>
    </operation>
</portType>
```

From  PortType.java

```
@RequestWrapper(localName="Request", targetNamespace="http://ws.site.no/path/to/service.xsd", className="path.to.request")
@WebMethod
@ResponseWrapper(localName="Response", targetNamespace="http://ws.site.no/path/to/service.xsd", className="path.to.request")
public void getResponse(
// Stuff from the request-class:
    @WebParam(name = "reference", targetNamespace = "")
    java.lang.String reference,
    @WebParam(name = "database", targetNamespace = "")
    path.to.Database database,
    @WebParam(name = "organizationNumber", targetNamespace = "")
    java.lang.String organizationNumber,

// Stuff from the response-class
    @WebParam(mode = WebParam.Mode.OUT, name = "Status", targetNamespace = "")
    javax.xml.ws.Holder<path.to.request.Status> status,
    @WebParam(mode = WebParam.Mode.OUT, name = "Information", targetNamespace = "")
    javax.xml.ws.Holder<path.to.request.Information> information,
    @WebParam(mode = WebParam.Mode.OUT, name = "Signature", targetNamespace = "")
    javax.xml.ws.Holder<path.to.request.Signature> signature,
   // (...) Everything else from the response class
) throws Error;
```

Comment: http://cxf.547215.n5.nabble.com/wsdl2java-and-holders-td548181.html

Comment: I didn't remember to answer this, but that link did help me back then. Thanks!